# Msg to everyone in same router?

Tags: router, ip, ipmsg

I got router in my home, and I would like to send message to everyone using it. I mean like one that will show up on their screen. I tried to look for answer, but it wasn't what I wanted. It would also be helpful if it could be done for specific IP.

Comment: That's technology I haven't actually seen since the 90s. The modern equivalent is a house full of Home Pods …Hey Siri, tell everyone dinner's ready ;)

Comment: Turn off the router, and let everyone come to you. That'll get the message across... No, I'm kidding. There's no way to do this. Another way is to use something like Slack, Discord, telegram, etc... and put everyone in the same group. You have to move them if their situation changes. If its for admin purpose, create a distribution list per router and put people in there. Don't forget to update the list if someone changes to a different router

Answer (score 1):

You could use in the Command Prompt (CMD) the
[msg command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg)
like this to send a message to all users logged on to the
computer named `someone`:

```
msg * /server:someone Hi everybody
```

If you have several computers to message regularly, you could create
a `.bat` file for all of them, like:

```
msg * /server:someone1 %*
msg * /server:someone2 %*
```

And it can be called by: `filename.bat this is my message`.

Comment: "This will send the message to everyone on the server." cst has not stated he has  server ...

Comment: I think it's the Messenger service or similar and that hasn't been enabled by default on Windows systems since Vista.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Wrong link corrected and missing information added. Life is good now.